# Convert JSON (with so many/undetermined childrens) to HTML list

Tags: html, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "name":"Tree",
  "id":"999999",
  "is_open":true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 1",
      "id":"1",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 1.1",
          "id":"1"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 1.2",
          "id":"2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 2",
      "id":"3",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 2.1",
          "id":"5"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 2.2",
          "id":"4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 3",
      "id":"3",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 3.1",
          "id":"5"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 3.2",
          "id":"4"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
```

I need to convert to a HTML list, like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Tree
        <ul>
            <li>Tree Step 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Tree Step 1.1</li>
                    <li>Tree Step 1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Tree Step 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Tree Step 2.1</li>
                    <li>Tree Step 2.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Tree Step 3
                <ul>
                    <li>Tree Step 3.1</li>
                    <li>Tree Step 3.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried several times in different ways, but could not solve it. It is important to remember that one child might have several childrens according to the user setting.

Has anyone done something like this and can help me?

[edit (to Blender and Dan Pichelman)]
One of my attempts using PHP (i didnt post to not overflow the question):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom_menu = $dom->createElement('ul');
$attr = $dom->createAttribute('id');
$attr->value = ('menu');
$dom_menu->appendChild($attr);
$dom->appendChild($dom_menu);

arvore($treeJson, $dom_menu);

function arvore($obj, $dom_pai) {
    global $cont;
    global $dom;
    global $dom_menu;

    $id = $obj->name."_".$cont."_".rand(1, 999);
    $qtd = count($obj->children);

    $uls = childrenPai($obj->children, $dom_menu);
}

function childrenPai($children, $pai) {
    global $dom;

    for ($i=0; $i<count($children); $i++) {
        $ul = $dom->createElement('ul');

        $li = criarLi($children[$i], "-");

        $ul->appendChild($li);
        $pai->appendChild($ul);

        $uls[] = $ul;
    }
    return $uls;
}


function criarLi($obj, $id) {
    global $dom;

    $e = $dom->createElement('li', $obj->name);
    $attr = $dom->createAttribute('id');
    $attr->value = $id."_".trim($obj->name);
    $e->appendChild($attr);
    $dom->appendChild($e);

    return $e;
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

That did not work properly. The HTML list was created with some "bugs".

Comment: "*I tried several times in different ways*". Can you post an example?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  What have you tried, and how did it fail to solve your problem?

Comment: In which language? Smarty? Plain PHP? .NET? This isn't a job for the client-side.

Comment: OK, sorry for that. I'm developing using PHP and javascript. The question was updated with one of my attempts. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/*
 * `jsn` -- described json
 * returns: 
 *   result -- html tree, so you can latter append it to some node;
 */
var parseJsonAsHTMLTree = function(jsn){
    var result = '';
    if(jsn.name){
        result += '<ul><li>' + jsn.name;        

        for(var i in jsn.children)
            result += parseJsonAsHTMLTree(jsn.children[i]); 

        result += '</li></ul>';
    }

    return result;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6esW8/1/

Comment: Hey ted, your solution is amazing... there is only a detail to set: the code is including a extra <ul></ul> between <li> "Step 1.1" and "Step 1.2"... I will try work on this...

Comment: Well... i didnt succeed on this :(

Comment: @user2157786, this (http://jsfiddle.net/6esW8/3/) may work for you, but it's a bit ugly

Answer (score 0):

So the confusing thing about this is that it is an object containing arrays containing objects containing arrays... so it makes parsing complicated.

I would use javascript and because of the html output that you are looking for probably jquery as well..

so given an object:

```
var jsonObject = {
  "name":"Tree",
  "id":"999999",
  "is_open":true,
  "children": [
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 1",
      "id":"1",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 1.1",
          "id":"1"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 1.2",
          "id":"2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 2",
      "id":"3",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 2.1",
          "id":"5"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 2.2",
          "id":"4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Tree Step 3",
      "id":"3",
      "is_open":true,
      "children":[
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 3.1",
          "id":"5"
        },
        {
          "name":"Tree Step 3.2",
          "id":"4"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
```

you could parse through it like so:

```
tree = jsonObject["name"]
 tree_step_1 = jsonObject['children'][0]['name']
 tree_step_1.1 = jsonObject['children'][0]['children'][0]['name']
```

and so on...

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/Sbaeq/28/)

I am using jquery to append the html onto the body element, and instead of saving each step to variables i am parsing the json as i go.

Because of the iterative nature of this structure you could construct of a for loop (.each() in jquery) that could pass over this and make this output more procedural

Comment: Jeremythuff, it is OK for this JSON, but that will change a lot. Depends on what user did to create the JSON. It is a system where user create a menu tree and could have 1, 2, 3... N levels